# List hidden value passes wrong value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list In my view. For each row, I view button and I am passing Id value as hidden. But when I click any button it is passing wrong hidden value to the controller. Always it passes the first-row hidden value to the controller.

View:

```html
@foreach (var list in Model)
{
      <div>
       <div > @( ((int)1) + @Model.IndexOf(list)).</div>
        <div >@list.details</div>
         <div class="col-md-2 row-index">
              <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit" name="action:view" id="view">View</button>
               <input type="hidden" name="viewId" id="viewId" value="list.WId" />
           </div>
      </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "view")]
public ActionResult ViewDetail(string viewId)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ViewDetails");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all values you need to change the input value type in your controller to array of strings.
I hope that this solution can help you

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "view")]
public ActionResult ViewDetail(string[] viewId)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ViewDetails");
}
```

if you want to get the exact value you need to duplicate the form within your foreach 
in this case you should write somthing like this :

```
 @foreach (var list in Model)
    {
          <div>
           <div > @( ((int)1) + @Model.IndexOf(list)).</div>
            <div >@list.details</div>
             <div class="col-md-2 row-index">
             <form ... > // complete your form attributes 
                  <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit" name="action:view" id="view">View</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="viewId" id="viewId" value="list.WId" />
              </form>
               </div>
          </div>
    }
```

**Note : You should delete the global form**

Answer (score 0):

You should have one form for each row. then you submit that row.
Otherwise as you state it passes first value.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting each value to the same element ID (which is invalid anyway) and name. When you submit your form (which would be more helpful to fully answer your question) it is finding the first element that matches that criteria and submitting it.

There are multiple ways to resolve this such as the already mentioned form per entry but the other preference would be to modify you button to a div and add a click handler to pass the specific value to a js function which would then submit to the controller. Its a preference choice regarding how tightly coupled you want your front end. But the main problem is your element naming convention.